# How to automatic slug when i press the submit button

Tags: laravel-5

I want to create slug by using value of **$item->name = $request->input('name');** before $item->save();

```
//use Illuminate\Support\Str;

 private function saveItem(Request $request, $item){
    $item->name = $request->input('name');
    $item->slug = Str::title($item->name,"-");


    $item->save();
  }
```

When the $item->name = $request->input('name') value is **Hello World**,

Then after slug the output will be **Hello-World**

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a slug using [the `Str::slug()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug):

```php
private function saveItem(Request $request, $item){
    $item->name = $request->input('name');
    $item->slug = Str::slug($item->name);


    $item->save();
}
```